# What's generic types T and U in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

What's generic types T and U in Swift?
take a look about function "func map(transform: (T) -> U) -> [U]"
What's the T?
What's the U?
Does T and U are different?

Comment: Its a generic closure that takes T as parameter and return U, T is the array type you want to map and U is the return type of what you want to extract

Comment: sorry about that. My point is what's T and what's U and what's difference between T and U.

Comment: fyi I didnt downvote ;), T and U are generics and can turn into different types basd on your input and what you put into the closure, check my answer for example.

Comment: When making a generic function yourself you can choose any alphabetical character you want, as long they are not the same. T and U are just standards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a generic closure that takes T as parameter and return U, T is the array type you want to map and U is the return type of what you want to extract

For example:

```
let map = ["",""].map { $0.isEmpty }
```

`T` is `[String]` and `U` is `[Bool]`